# Page loaded within page --> Forwarding to index.html when page is loaded alone

Tags: javascript, html, forwarding

I wrote a website that uses a JavaScript loader to load html-files within the index.html into a specific div.
The loaded html page on its own looks like this:

```
<div id="pageloader">
    CONTENT
</div> <!-- END #pageloader -->
```

Naturally, when the page is loaded on it's own, there are no stylesheets connected to it and the rest of the index.html is missing.

Is there a way to automatically forward to the index.html when the "loader-page" is accessed on it's own? I tried a simple forwarding by adding this header to the "loader-page" but now it always forwards to the index.html even when the "loader-page" is accessed through the index.html.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://...">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little quick-'n'-dirty but you could set a variable in the loader that the included page checks.

In your loader:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var loader = 1;
</script>
```

In the loaded page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (loader != 1) {
    window.location = "/index.html";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Now it won't load the page within the index.html and when accessed directly it's just displayed like it was without the javascript.

Comment: What does "won't load the page" mean?

Comment: It means that the page won't be displayed. The ajax-loader just spins and doesn't fade away as programmed. Like as if the script is broken and doesn't finish.